# Change SSH host for cloning

Tags: gitlab

Is there any way to change default ssh host for gitlab (displayed at top of repository view in web interface)? I mean only for SSH in clone urls.

For example I have my gitlab installation on `git.example.com`, but `example.com` also points to the same machine (different site). Can I change ssh clone urls from:

```
git clone git@git.example.com:user/repository
```

to:

```
git clone git@example.com:user/repositiory
```

but for http and https leave it with `git.example.com`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes,

If you are using the omnibus package you can edit `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and add `gitlab_rails['gitlab_ssh_host'] = 'example.host.com'`

There is the equivalent option somewhere in `gitlab.yml` : `ssh_host: example.host.com`

Comment: In gitlab.yml it should put in gitlab_shell section, and it works also on 6.6.x version, not only on newest one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If your subdomain behaves the same way your actual domain does, it should not be a problem. If  the subdomain points to the same IP, git or ssh for that matter should not bother.

Comment: But I mean to change default host, displayed in web interface in clone url.

Comment: As far as I know these are derived from the same config setting, so not without hacking core

Comment: It turns out that it is possible and quite easy, even for version 6.6.5 that was newest one in time of asking this question. Thanks anyway.